# How can I get data from a HTML form to JavaScript file and to add MySQL?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have created two files: index.html and main.js. How I can get data from index.html file to main.js file and insert the in database?

index.html

```html
// html form
    <form method="POST" action = "">

    <input type="text"  id="name" name ="name" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="number"  id="age"  name="age" placeholder="Age">
            <select  id="gender"  name="gender">
        <option value = "male" >Male</option>
        <option value = "female">Female</option>
      </select>
            <input type="text"  id="phone"  name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>

      </form>
```

I want to create a function whick send a index.html file on request and take data from that file and add to MySQL database.

main.js

```javascript
    // creating connection to mysql databases
    var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host:'localhost',
        user:'root',
        password:'1234',
        database:'project1'
    });
    // checking connection
    con.connect(function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log('error connecting to database');
        }else{
            console.log('connected to databases');
        }
    });
    var publicPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '/');

   app.get('/', function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join('index.html',{root:publicPath}));
    });
    app.listen(5000, function() {
      console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:5000/');
    });
```

Comment: The action attribute should be set to the url of the file which will save the data. Also set the method attribute to post. The code you have to save the data??? Use mysqli functions mysql is depreciated. You need to look at some examples and do more research.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could use this JavaScript function

document.getElementById('name').value

This could be used with an IF statement:

if(document.getElementById('age').value == 100) {

}

I don't know about MySQL yet.